# Occurences of a letter in a phrase

Tags: java, string

I am getting the below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   HashMap.CountLetters.tallyPrint(CountLetters.java:12) at
>   HashMap.CountLetters.main(CountLetters.java:21)

The goal is to get store the occurrences of each letter in a `HashMap`. The key is the letter and the value is the # of occurrences.

```
package HashMap;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class CountLetters {
    public HashMap tallyPrint(String phrase) {
        int count = 0;
        HashMap<String, Integer> fav = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i<phrase.length(); i++)
        {
            if (fav.containsKey(phrase.substring(i,i+1)))
                fav.put("" + phrase.substring(i,i+1), fav.get(phrase)+1);
            else
                fav.put("" + phrase.substring(i,i+1),1);
        }
        return fav;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CountLetters x = new CountLetters();
        System.out.println(x.tallyPrint("my feet smell and my nose runs"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more details about the exception you're getting? Particularly, put a comment on the line that it happens on, and post the full stack trace?

Comment: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at HashMap.CountLetters.tallyPrint(CountLetters.java:12)
 at HashMap.CountLetters.main(CountLetters.java:21)
'

Comment: Please edit your question instead. Don't post your stack trace in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace
`fav.put("" + phrase.substring(i,i+1), fav.get(phrase)+1);`

with:

`fav.put("" + phrase.substring(i,i+1), fav.get(phrase.substring(i,i+1))+1);`

Side note1: You should extract that `substring` and store it in a temp variable to be more efficient so you don't keep calling `substring` over and over for the same substring.

Side note2: Thanks for posting the whole (with the main method) in your question. It's make it simpler if all the askers did it like this.

Comment: Putting the whole code is only good if it's a [simple, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 2):

In

```
fav.put("" + phrase.substring(i,i+1), fav.get(phrase)+1)
```

the subexpression

```
fav.get(phrase)
```

should be

```
fav.get(phrase.substring(i,i+1))
```

You're trying to increment a count, but instead of getting the prior value to add 1 to, you're getting the value for an unrelated key and as a result you get a `NullPointerException` trying to auto-unbox `null` to an `int`.

Comment: no because I need to increase the count if the letter is a key in the hashmap already

Comment: @Prasanth, please see my expanded comments.

Comment: @Prasanth `fav.get(phrase)` isn't getting the current letter's count. `phrase` at this point is `"my feet smell and my nose runs"`, not `"m"` or `"y"`, so it's returning a `null` value. When Java tries to do `null + 1` (`fav.get(phrase) + 1`) it throws the exception.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Could you add something about why `HashMap<Character, Integer>` and `String.charAt(i)` would be a much better answer, I'd do it myself but answering the original part of the question would be virtually the same as yours.

Comment: @durron597, I think it would be a better solution because treating a character as distinct from a string would cause this error to be caught by the type-checker.  It might be marginally more efficient too and would be easier to adapt to count code-points.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `charAt()` here and not sub-string as that is giving the `NPE` as you are trying to read address 1 more character.

#### Full code

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CountLetters {
    public HashMap tallyPrint(String phrase) {
        int count = 0;
        HashMap<Character, Integer> fav = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i<phrase.length(); i++) {
            if (fav.containsKey(phrase.charAt(i))) 
                fav.put(phrase.charAt(i), (fav.get(phrase.charAt(i)))+1);
            else
                fav.put(phrase.charAt(i),1);
        }
        return fav;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CountLetters x = new CountLetters();
        System.out.println(x.tallyPrint("my feet smell and my nose runs"));
    }
}
```

#### Output

> {f=1,  =6, d=1, e=4, a=1, n=3, o=1, l=2, m=3, u=1, t=1, s=3, r=1, y=2}

Comment: If that's your actual output, then your code is wrong (which it is).

Comment: @cHao He did `"" + char`, so no, he boxed it himself.

Comment: Sorry took some time to update the correct piece of code here. Have updated now.

Comment: @mtk: This is good, but it's even better to use a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` than doing all that `String` construction